# Query posts based on tags in user model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm using Django Fabulous to create a tagging system for a project I'm working on. I want to display posts that have tags similar to the users' skills in their profile. Any solution or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

The error I get is `'TagDescriptor' object is not iterable` which I think is related to JobPosts\views.py.

JobPosts\models.py (Works fine)

```
class Skill(tagulous.models.TagTreeModel):
    class TagMeta:
        initial = [
            'Python/Django',
            'Python/Flask',
            'JavaScript/JQuery',
            'JavaScript/Angular.js',
            'Linux/nginx',
            'Linux/uwsgi',
        ]
        space_delimiter = False
        force_lowercase = True
        max_count = 5
        protected = True


class JobPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    jobskill = tagulous.models.TagField(Skill)
```

JobPosts/views.py (This is where I need help)

```
def job_post_list_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser:
        my_qs = JobPost.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    elif request.user.is_authenticated:
        my_qs = JobPost.objects.filter(Q(user=request.user) | Q(jobskill__in=User.userskill))
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context = {
        'job_list': my_qs
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

JobPosts\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('browse/', views.job_post_list_view, name='job_post_list'),
]
```

home.html

```
{% for object in job_list %}
    {% include 'jobpost/post.html' with job_post=object truncate=True detail=False %}
{% endfor %}
```

UserManager\models.py

```
from JobPosts.models import Skill

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    u_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    userskill = tagulous.models.TagField(Skill, blank=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `Q(jobskill__in=User.userskill` which says "of all the JobPost objects, find the ones where the jobskill is one of the userskill attribute of the User model"

You need to change that to "is one of the userskills of the user I'm interested in":

`Q(jobskill__in=request.user.userskill`

Comment: I had tried that previously and this is the error I get: 'TagRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: Oh of course - try `Q(jobskill__in=request.user.userskill.all())`